# BootstrapVue conditional column in b-table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'd like to only show one of my columns if the current user is an admin. I'm not sure how to do this with bootstrapVue. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a computed prop to filter you `fields` definition array based on some condition (i.e. admin access), and then pass the computed prop to `<b-table>` as the `fields` prop value.  Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do the filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet based on Troy's comment.

I've added a custom property to the field object called `requiresAdmin`. This is not part of standard `Bootstrap-Vue`.

You can use this to filter out all the fields that require's the user to be an admin in a computed property. Based on whether the user is an admin or not. This makes it easy to add and remove fields that require's the user to be an admin.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    computedFields() {
      // If the user isn't an admin, filter out fields that require auth.
      if(!this.isUserAdmin)
        return this.fields.filter(field => !field.requiresAdmin);
        
      // If the user IS an admin, return all fields.
      else
        return this.fields;
    }
  },
  data() {
      return {
        isUserAdmin: false,
        fields: [
          { key: 'first', label: 'First Name' },
          { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name' },
          { key: 'age', label: 'Age' },
          { key: 'sex', label: 'Sex' },
          { key: 'secretActions', label: 'Secret Actions', requiresAdmin: true },
        ],
        items: [
          { first: 'John', last: 'Doe', sex: 'Male', age: 42 },
          { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', sex: 'Female', age: 36 },
          { first: 'Rubin', last: 'Kincade', sex: 'Male', age: 73 },
          { first: 'Shirley', last: 'Partridge', sex: 'Female', age: 62 }
        ]
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.3.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.3.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-btn @click="isUserAdmin = !isUserAdmin">
    Toggle admin user ({{ isUserAdmin }})
  </b-btn>
  <br /><br />
  <b-table :fields="computedFields" :items="items">
    <template v-slot:cell(secretActions)>
      <b-btn>Edit User</b-btn>
      <b-btn>Delete User</b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: return this.fields.filter(field => this.isUserAdmin || !field.requiresAdmin);